# Is HTTP "good enough" for non-public services?

Tags: security, http, networking, https

I'm creating a handful of microservices on Heroku that all need to talk amongst each other. The layout is something like this:

```
             User making requests
                       |
Service #1 ------ Web server ------ Authentication server
                       |
                  Service #2
```

Since they're all on Heroku, there's no internal net---they're all on the wide-open internet. I suspect that HTTPS for these internal services would be overkill---conceivably, the only third parties I'd have to worry about intercepting the communications would be:

1. Heroku (who has all my code and data anyways)
2. Heroku's network provider (well, technically AWS)
3. The NSA (they probably have all my data anyways)

Assuming I'm willing to live with the above risks, **am I ok with using just HTTP for my microservices?**

Comment: No. You need to be using HTTPS. End of story.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use HTTPS and be done with it.

It's not overkill. With modern processors the overhead is minimal. Yes you need certificates, but in this case even self-signed certificates are OK **provided that you manually load the cert to the client**. That way the identity of the server can be authenticated.

TLS protects against multiple vectors:

- Data leakage

  That a malicious person can read your data
- Data tampering

  That a malicious person can tamper with your data
- Service spoofing

  That a malicious person can pretend to be the server in question.

If you trust the infrastructure (and that's a BIG if), then you don't need to worry about 1 or 2. But you still need to worry about 3, since unless you're doing **everything** off of IP addresses on a vlan, attack vectors may still exist.

However, why trust the infrastructure when you have tools to not have to trust them?

It's not like HTTPS is expensive...

Answer (score 1):

**HTTPS is really the way to go.**

The problems with HTTP

- **The information isn't encrypted**
- **No certs, what if someone re-routes their dns on your application, there's nothing proving that you're connected to the right person**

**It's worth thinking about your audience as well, whether they'd appreciate it or not.**

- If it's a large application, it's a must have.
- if it's a very small
  audience, you'll have to weigh the effort of doing it now, vs doing
  it later when it expands

Mind you if it's an embedded system it can be a pain in the arse to use ssl, but it's well worth it for piece of mind. 2 cents